# Is dynamic shader translation possible?

Tags: opengl, directx, emulation, emulator, hardware-acceleration

I know there's dynamic binary translation/JITs, but what about dynamic shader translators?

I'm writing an emulator for a system that uses a very particular, custom graphics processor, but I'd like to mimic its shader code in software a bit (no HW acceleration); then I'd like to re-structure the shader code to fit the real pipeline for the target GPU such as to speed it up by doing so dynamically.

Is this possible? I'd like to do it similar to how JIT can speed up programs that need translation before finalized execution, but do so with the HW accelerated pipeline (e.g., DX/OpenGL with shaders).

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but OpenGL compiles GLSL code "on the fly" at driver, so in that respect, it is a JIT compiler; OpenGL just normally does not have GLSL interpreters at all. DX - I have understood - does the compilation at compile time. You can have intermediate languages which get translated to GLSL and then compiled to shader, or any other system that can create GLSL source at runtime to let GPU to do the work for you.